# i cant open any unity HDRP projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering

when ever i open any project with HDRP in it, unity tells me to launch it in safe mode because it finds many compillation errors:
[image: errors]

i tried downloading different versions, reinstalling packages and unity, running as admin... nothing works.

if anyone knows whats wrong with it i will be really really happy for help.
this prevents me from contenuing to work on my project sadly :(

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

try to delete everything in this folder

```
PackageCache: [project path]/library/PackageCache
```

and re-open your project.

Comment: tried that, also tried to remove the entire library and change versions of different packages, nothing worked. im guessing this is a bug with unity...

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in unity.

the only solution to this is to wait until unity 2021.3 releases, and updating your project would fix this.
i contacted unity about this, apperently the only solution is to go back to a safe version (like unity 2019.4 LTS), and than downgrading the XR MANAGER PACKAGE to 3.2.16.
if your project, like mine, is built and requires unity 2021 to work, the best option we have right now is wait for it to be fixed.

hope this helped!